# remove libavcodec54

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-restricted-extras

In the Xubuntu offline documentation it says:

> It will be necessary to install "xubuntu-restricted-extras" in order
>   to play proprietary media formats like e.g. MP3.

At the Ubuntu Software Center it says:

> To install "Xubuntu restricted extras", these items must be removed:
>   "Libav codec library" and   "libavcodec54"

There is a "Libav codec library" which consist of many different items in two folders. 10 items in folder "info" lokated at `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and other items in some other folder.

Then the "libavcodec54" file in folder "override" located at `/usr/share/lintian/overrides`. I found the location by using the feature "Find in this folder"

And every single file has to be removed?
After that I'm able to install the: "xubuntu-restricted-extras" ?

Do I understand this correctly?

Are there any risks?

Comment: You have to remove the packages, not the files from the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to remove anything by yourself. Just command `apt` or the Software Centre to install the `xubuntu-restricted-extras` package and everything else will be taken care of automatically.

Comment: I commanded the Software Centre to install anyway. Without removing anything myself. And it installed.

Comment: Good, that was the expected behaviour.

Comment: I think I just pressed the arrows to the left, without knowing what they were ment fore. It's aknowlege system? The fact is that I followed your advise, but haven't yet been able to check if it actually works since my player displays a message: Error, GStreamer backend error. Could not handle CDDA URI